# Advertise Chat on Front Page

Tags: feature-request, site-improvement, chat

On some other StackExchange sites there is a small box to display chat status.

[image: chat status on bicycles.SE]

We have this status box on meta, but on the main site it seems to be missing.
Or as @Grohlier put it [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7645932#7645932).

> Once you realize where the button is you go, "OHHHHHHHhhhhhh."

I think it would be good to add this info box to the front page to get more people in the chat.