# How can I find the chat rooms of the Fitness stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

Every other SE I participate in has a link to the chat rooms on the main page. [It doesn't seem to be the case on the Fitness SE.](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/418/advertise-chat-on-front-page) So where are the chat rooms? How can I find them?

Answer (score 3):

Click the SE-style hamburger menu. There's a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=fitness.stackexchange.com) link beside the site name that will show all chat rooms linked to this site, including the main chat room: [The Locker Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room).

[image: chat link on SE hamburger menu]